# How to remove a wrong synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

By mistake I'd created [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) as a synonym for iPhone, actually its wrong, now my question is **how can I remove that synonym?**

Here's the link for `iPhone` tag,
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone/synonyms

[image]

Comment: That's only a *suggested* synonym. It'll be deleted when downvoted far enough. I've added my DV to it. (I'm actually surprised I have enough score on that tag to vote!)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes! You're right. Its clearly stated that, a synonym with a -2 score will be deleted automatically. Thanks btw :)

Comment: It's gone, second vote killed it.

Comment: @Mat, Yes, it's become invisible! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already written out that, that's only a suggested synonym, which will go prior to moderators and they will have choice to approve or reject the suggested synonym.

For that, they can upvote or down vote on suggested synonyms. If a synonym will get 4 upvotes then it'll get approved, if it'll score -2 (that's negative) it will get rejected, and will delete from the list.